# Multiple Progress Bar States in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-7, progress-bar

I'm currently developing a WPF application in C# and I want to have a progress bar control that can be in a "paused" state as well as an "error" state. Much like this: http://wyday.com/windows-7-progress-bar/ Unfortunately, that's a Windows Forms control and implementing it via a Windows Forms Host proved to be incompatible.

My question is, how can I go about accomplishing a similar effect in WPF? Is it possible to make multiple "states" of a progress bar? Is this kind of operation in WPF but I'm just looking over it? I'm mainly talking about the progress bar itself here, I'm pretty sure I know how to achieve this in the taskbar.

All help is appreciated, especially code examples. Thanks!

Comment: You are probably interested in some free code you can just paste. Instead I can only mention superb Actipro WPF Studio. They include the exact [progress control](http://www.actiprosoftware.com/Products/DotNet/WPF/Shared/WindowsControls.aspx) you are looking for but it's not free.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I'll have to look into that and maybe even purchase it since I'm going to be doing a lot of work in WPF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's certainly easy to change the color and style of the WPF Progress Bar, if that's what you mean.

Marquee Style = `progressBar1.IsIndeterminate = true;`

Error State = `progressBar1.Foreground = Brushes.Red`;

Paused State = `progressBar1.Foreground = Brushes.Yellow`;

Normal State =

```
            Brush newBrush = new SolidColorBrush(){Color = new Color(){A = 255, R = 1, G = 211,B=28}};
            progressBar1.Foreground = newBrush;
```

Note that I am not really that up to date with the progress bar colors, you might have to experiment a bit with the values above to get it just right.

Comment: I'll give this a try and get back to you!